# Compiling library with SSE2 and AVX2

Tags: c++, visual-studio, simd

Using VS2015 and compiling a library that has both SSE2 instructions and AVX2 instructions (that are only used if detected in the CPU), if I compile the library with `/arch:AVX2` but only call the SSE2 instructions I get "illegal instruction" (on `_mm_set1_epi32` first SSE2 instruction called). However, if I compile the lib with `/arch:SSE2` it works fine when calling the SSE2 instructions.

Are the arch settings mutually exclusive? If not how should this be fixed? I have attempted both as a shared lib and static lib with the same issue.

this is the lib: https://github.com/Auburns/FastNoiseSIMD and there is an issue about it https://github.com/Auburns/FastNoiseSIMD/issues/20, although I don't think the related it directly to AVX2 being on and calling SSE2 instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you build with `/arch:AVX` or `/arch:AVX2`, the *primary* impact is that all SSE code generated by the compiler will use the [VEX prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VEX_prefix) encoding which allows for more efficient scheduling of registers. If you run such code on a system without AVX or AVX2 support, it will in fact fault with an illegal instruction.

In other words, your use of `_mm_set1_epi32` is an SSE2 instruction, but because you built with `/arch:AVX2` it emitted those instructions using the VEX prefix. The `/arch` switch impacts explicit intrinsics, compiler-generated floating-point math, the autovectorizer, etc.

If you want to support both 'stock' SSE/SSE2, AVX, and AVX2 platforms with optimized codepaths using the automatic generation supported by the `/arch` switch, you need three different binaries (EXEs or DLLs).

> See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/09/11/directxmath-avx/) as well as [this one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/06/03/directxmath-avx2/)

Note the main difference between `/arch:AVX` and `/arch:AVX2` is that the compiler will sometimes emit FMA3 instructions where the scheduler thinks it would be faster than a multiply then an add.